# Full screen width div area

Tags: html, css

What's the best approach to creating a div that will take the full width of the screen, no matter what resolution? I'm trying to add a 'top' bar and bottom 'footer' area with divs that have a black background and styled border that I'd create with a small image and repeat. For some reason my attempts are leading to small spaces on the top and sides of the div?

**My markup is similar to:**

```
<div id="top">

Top bar stuff

</div>

<div id="pagewrap">

All the page content

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top {

width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color:#000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `top:0;` and `left: 0;`  and you can also eliminate `padding: 0`. Don't use `top: 0;` for other div except top, use `left: 0;` for other div for eliminate the left space.

```
#top {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color:#000
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Usually this is the **`body` tag having some paddings and/or margins**. Try adding:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If this works, you may want to consider [using a normalization stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11578327/419956) that fixes this type of issue as well as many other related types of issues.

**Extended answer...**

The above answers the core issue folks landing here seem to have. But to expand a bit, try to directly answer the original question, and also providing some staple code that I use for things nowaydays:

Here's how I would create a full-width, but also full-height div inside a body in a cross-browser (but modern browser only) way:

```js
document.getElementById("pagewrap").innerHTML = "All the page content<br>".repeat(100);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* not completely needed, yet useful */
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex; /* or css grid for more intricate layouts */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#top {
  background-color: LightCoral;
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid Crimson;
}

#pagewrap {
  background-color: LightGreen;
  flex-grow: 1; /* make it stretch to the bottom even if little content */
  overflow-y: scroll; /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div id="top">Top bar stuff</div>
<div id="pagewrap">All the page content</div>
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me.

Comment: I was looking for the same!

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that `body` has `padding` and `margin` set to `0` in CSS.